# DNS-SD for HoloLens Device Portal

Tags: hololens, dns-sd

Anyone has used DNS-SD to discover the presence of HoloLens' Device Portal on the local network? Though docs claim it does advertise itself, I have found this very unstable and discovery is very random. It does show up for a while and then disappears for hours. Anyone can suggest a reliable way I can detect the presence of HoloLens on my local network?

Comment: I use the feature. Please clarify what kind of network do use? The common usecase is IPoverUSB network on USB3 cable from power port. The HL could be very energy consuming in other case and may optimise the data.

Comment: I want to discover the presence of HL on a common WiFi network, i.e. discover the IP address which is supposed to be advertised via DNS-SD.

Comment: I am not sure that the problem has an universal solution because it depends on frequency of re-publishing of device's information and life-time of updates on routers/servers. Stability might involve deep re-configuration of all network devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like HoloLens is not very keen to respond to IPv4 broadcasts; it does, but it'd better not respond at all than respond randomly making it look like it works, when it doesn't. Fortunately it is pretty reliable in responding to IPv6 broadcasts and the response actually includes it's both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, which solves my problem. Make sure that DNS-SD (MDNS) library you're using supports IPv6.